# Can one get IP interface names under Windows Phone 8.1?

Tags: windows-phone-8, ip-address, hotspot

A C++ cross-platform app I'm developing needs to enumerate all active IPs on a device and differentiate between a Wi-Fi IP and a hotspot IP.  The way I've done it is by comparing the *IP interface names*.  On platforms like Android and iOS, the interface names differ enough to be able to tell them apart (using functions like Linux's [getifaddrs()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getifaddrs.3.html) and [ioctl (socket, SIOCGIFCONF, &ifconf)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ioctl.2.html)).  [On iOS](https://jorudolph.wordpress.com/2011/07/22/ios-detect-personal-hotspot/), for example, the Wi-Fi interface always has the name "en0" while the hotspot interface name always begins with the string "bridge" (e.g., "bridge100").

I'm now targeting Windows Phone 8.1:

- Is there a way to enumerate interface names (not adapter names) under WP8.1?
- Can one differentiate between a Wi-Fi and a hotspot IP under WP8.1?
- Is there a way to do this in general under WinRT (Windows Runtime) 8.x?
- Is there a way to do it in C++/CX?

There are Windows functions for enumerating interface information (e.g., GetAdaptersInfo) but [they are not supported under WP8.1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br205759.aspx), and they do not provide an interface name.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

You might try the [Quickstart: Retrieving network connection information](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700381.aspx) article. Granted, it outlines the JavaScript library calls, but they're analogous in C++/C#. For instance, using the [NetworkInformation.GetConnectionProfiles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.connectivity.networkinformation.getconnectionprofiles.aspx) method, your code might look something like:

```
// Retrieve all active connections
var connectionProfiles = NetworkInformation.GetConnectionProfiles();

foreach (var connProfile in connectionProfiles)
{
    // Get all network names that alias this connection's IP
    var theNames = connProfile.GetNetworkNames();
    if (theNames.Any(name => name == "My Desired Name"))
    {
        // Do the thing
    }
}
```

The ConnectionProfile class also contains a [ProfileName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.connectivity.connectionprofile.profilename.aspx) property that may be somewhat indicative of what type of connection this profile identifies, but I suspect that is not necessarily the kind of information you are seeking.

Regarding identifying the connection type, you can use the [NetworkAdapter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.connectivity.connectionprofile.networkadapter.aspx) property object's [IanaInterfaceType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.connectivity.networkadapter.ianainterfacetype.aspx) property to get more information about the type of connection.

```
foreach (var connProfile in connectionProfiles)
{
    if (connProfile.NetworkAdapter.IanaInterfaceType == 71) {
        // Take action related to IEEE 802.11 wireless network connection
    }
}
```

These methods and properties are supported for the universal Windows 8.1 runtime.

Comment: I will certainly check this out.  Regardless on where it takes me, kudos and an up-tick for stepping in with an interesting direction -- thanks!